# Web app development with following req(wcf compulsory)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I got one task which I am unable to do... The task is like this: I need to develop an ASP.NET web site which has the following two sections:

1. A text box where the user can type a message and hit the broadcast button.
2. Where all the messages being broadcast by any user can be seen (real time message feed, new messages should appear without need of reloading the page/hitting a button).

Comment: Sounds like something very similar to a publish-subscribe model.  Your client would send a message to the service which would then send it to all other clients subscribed to the service.  Google "WCF Publish Subscribe" for some examples - play around with them, and if you get stuck on a particular part of the code, come back and ask regarding that part.  Your current question is rather broad and will most likely get closed.

Answer (score 3):

If WCF is not mandatory, look into [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

From signalr.net:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

Its easy to implement, well documented, and it can be used for more than just browser/html based clients. They even have some [sample chat applications](https://github.com/SignalR/Samples) that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: +1 for adding some explanation about SignalR and how it might apply to OP's project.